# App Search - How to add "multi field", a field with array of values (like color)

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-appsearch, elastic-search-ui

I am trying to use App Search, and when I index a document that looks like:

```
name: 'metalica t-shirt'
colors: ['red', 'black']
```

The engine removes 'black' and leaves it as:

```
name: 'metalica t-shirt'
colors: 'red'
```

But I want it to appear both under 'red' color and 'black' color filter on Search UI, is it supported?

Comment: How you are indexing data ?

Comment: @SagarPatel trought the document API